# How to escape special characters in Groovy, excluding unicode

Tags: java, unicode, groovy, escaping

I would like to escape all the special characters in a string except for unicode characters (\u), since I would still like to display non-English characters correctly. I am currently using the StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava() method, but have not found a way to exclude specific characters (\u for unicode, in this instance). The only alternative I can think of is to call replace or replaceAll for each special character except \u, which doesn't seem ideal. Is there a better way to do this?

Ex:

```
"Los 
niños"
```

should be converted to `"Los\nniños"` instead of `"Los\nni\u00F1os"`

Comment: I don't understand ... why not just choose an appropriate encoding?

Comment: @tim_yates the framework I'm using defaults to UTF-8. I'd prefer to stick with that if possible, but do you have a recommendation for an encoding that would work for this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you better explain why you are doing this encoding?

Comment: @tim_yates using UTF-8 b/c that's what the rest of our framework uses and it encodes non-latin characters correctly, but this can be changed easily enough, as long as a new encoding also encodes non-latin characters correctly. Formatting the output string this way because I am sending the data to a third party who expects the input in this form; they parse/display the data that we send them.

Comment: Yeah, but why are you passing it through `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava`

Comment: @tim_yates that seemed like the quickest way to escape all special characters, but I didn't anticipate that this would affect non-latin characters. Essentially I'm trying to find an approach similar to escapeJava except where I can ignore certain special characters like \u.

Comment: But why send `\n` as two characters rather than just send the newline character as in the original string?

Comment: @tim_yates specifically requested by the receiver of the data. not exactly sure why they need this.

Comment: Ahhh...been there ;-)  Think I may have a solution...posting below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if we look into the code of `StringEscapeUtils`, we can see the [`escapeJava` method here](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.java#L454):

```
public static final String escapeJava(final String input) {
    return ESCAPE_JAVA.translate(input);
}
```

Which uses `ESCAPE_JAVA` [which is defined here](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.java#L53)

```
public static final CharSequenceTranslator ESCAPE_JAVA = 
      new LookupTranslator(
        new String[][] { 
          {"\"", "\\\""},
          {"\\", "\\\\"},
      }).with(
        new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.JAVA_CTRL_CHARS_ESCAPE())
      ).with(
        JavaUnicodeEscaper.outsideOf(32, 0x7f) 
    );
```

So, I think it's this last bit which is giving you the undesired escaping...

So we can roll our own...  Given your input string:

```
def input = '''Los 
niños'''
```

We can import the classes, and create our own `LookupTranslator` (ripping off the first bits from commons-lang):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.EntityArrays
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.LookupTranslator

def translator = new LookupTranslator([["\"", "\\\""], ["\\", "\\\\"]] as String[][]).with(
    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.JAVA_CTRL_CHARS_ESCAPE())
)
```

And then, we can escape your input String, and check the result is as expected:

```
assert translator.translate(input) == 'Los \\nniños'
```

If you need the escaping for the unicode chars below 32 (but obviously, not the higher code chars), you can change your translator to:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.EntityArrays
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.JavaUnicodeEscaper
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.LookupTranslator

def translator = new LookupTranslator([["\"", "\\\""], ["\\", "\\\\"]] as String[][]).with(
    new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.JAVA_CTRL_CHARS_ESCAPE())
).with(JavaUnicodeEscaper.below(32))
```

All these are from commons-lang3 which I assume is the version you are using...